# Protractor image upload doesn't work on IE and firefox

Tags: javascript, selenium, file-upload, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to upload image  on the input type:file control using protractor.

I am using the below code:

```
var basePath='../testdata/testappicons/accepted';
var randomIcon=randomIntFromInterval(1,6);
var overallPathToIcon=basePath+randomIcon+'.png';
var fileToUpload = overallPathToIcon;
console.log(fileToUpload);
var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload)
browser.executeScript('$(\'input[type="file"]\').attr("style", "");');
$('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

The above code works well on the chrome and I am able to upload files but when I use the same code on firefox and IE. I get the following error:

> ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not displayed

This is the HTML for the form:

```
div class="fileUpload" ng-click="IsInValid=true">
<label class="btn btn-white uploadBtn" title="Upload image file" for="upload-image">
<input id="uploadFile" type="text" readonly="" placeholder="Browse new app icon" value="maxsizepngfile.png">
<input id="upload-image" class="upload ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope" type="file" ng-model="image" image="appicon" accept="image/*">
</label>
<label class="btn btn-warning" for="upload-image">
<span>Browse</span>
</label>
</div>
```

My guess is this since it is a read only this is why it isn't working. Can anyone please help me out on this?

This is the code that got working for me

```
var basePath='../testdata/testappicons/accepted';
        var randomIcon=randomIntFromInterval(1,6);
      var overallPathToIcon=basePath+randomIcon+'.png';
          var fileToUpload = overallPathToIcon;
          console.log(fileToUpload);
      var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload)
      //browser.executeScript('$(\'input[type="file"]\').attr("style", "");');

        var elm = $('input[type="file"]');  // protractor's shortcut to element(by.css("css"))
        //browser.executeScript('var input = $("input:file"); var elm = input[0];elm.style.visibility = "visible"; elm.style.height = "1px"; elm.style.width = "1px";elm.style.opacity = 1;');

        browser.executeScript('var input = $("input:file"); input[0].removeAttribute("class");');
        elm.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

Comment: Try to un-hide your element the way it is described here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_Does_WebDriver_support_file_uploads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would still be a guess, but an educated one: do not involve jQuery in setting the `style`:

```
var elm = $('input[type="file"]');  // protractor's shortcut to element(by.css("css"))
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].style = {};', elm.getWebElement());

elm.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

Also, to follow the @dmitankin's comment and the [Does WebDriver support file uploads?](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_Does_WebDriver_support_file_uploads?) FAQ section, try making the element visible this way:

```
function makeVisible(arguments) {
    var elm = arguments[0];

    elm.style.visibility = 'visible'; 
    elm.style.height = '1px'; 
    elm.style.width = '1px';
    elm.style.opacity = 1;
}
browser.executeScript(makeVisible, elm.getWebElement());
```

Comment: This is the error I get on IE ` ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not displayed (WARNING: The server did n
ot provide any stacktrace information)`                                                                                             I am using the code as per your suggestion <code>       var elm = $('input[type="file"]');  // protractor's shortcut to element(by.css("css"))
        browser.executeScript('var input = $("input:file"); var elm = input[0];elm.style.visibility = "visible"; elm.style.height = "1px"; elm.style.width = "1px";elm.style.opacity = 1;');
</code>

Comment: @SandyRocks okay, what about `browser.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('class');", elm.getWebElement());`?

Comment: Thanks alot. This worked the code I used was                                                                                                                  
        browser.executeScript('var input = $("input:file"); input[0].removeAttribute("class");');
        elm.sendKeys(absolutePath);

Comment: @alecxe how would you put the visible function in the upload element function I'm not quite understanding.. is arguments a variable I pass in? I'm so confused.  However I also cant get uploads to work on ie or firefox.

Comment: @NicolePhillips let's take a look at your use case. Could you please elaborate your problem into a separate question and throw me a link here? I'll take a look. Thanks!