# For loop protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am very new to protractor and still getting my head around promises btu am trying to do a, what I see as, a simple for loop. Basically I have an imbedded text editor that I cannot use the (element...).clear(); function with due to the element not being able to be interactive with.

So I would like to get the text length(x) in the text editor and then press the backspace x number of times, clearing the text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
element(by.css("div[class='ace_content']")).getText().then(function(textvalue) {
   for (var i = textvalue.length; i == 0; i--) {
      console.log("i =" + i)
      element(by.css("div[class*='ace_editor'] > textarea")).sendKeys(protractor.Key.BACK_SPACE);
   }
```

Comment: Could you create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make it simpler - select all the text in the editor and push backspace once:

```
var editor = element(by.css("div.ace_content")),
    keys = protractor.Key;
browser.actions()
    .click(editor)
    .sendKeys(keys.chord(keys.COMMAND, "a"))  
    .sendKeys(keys.BACKSPACE)
    .perform();
```

`keys.CONTROL` on windows.

FYI, here is a cross-platform way to handle the CTRL/COMMAND automagically:

- [Using cross-platform keyboard shortcuts in end-to-end testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263091/using-cross-platform-keyboard-shortcuts-in-end-to-end-testing)

Here is a sample test that demonstrates how does it work (using the [ACE Editor Demo page](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about)):

```
describe("Ace editor", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get("https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about");
    });

    it("should change the ace editor text", function () {
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions,
            editor = $(".ace_content"),
            keys = protractor.Key;

        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(editor), 5000);

        browser.actions()
            .click(editor)
            .sendKeys(keys.chord(keys.COMMAND, "a"))
            .sendKeys(keys.BACKSPACE)
            .sendKeys("test")
            .perform();

        expect($(".ace_identifier").getText()).toEqual("test");
    });
});
```

---

Note that there is always that invisible `textarea` element that is behind the Ace Editor wrapper. You can alternatively [make it visible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30725189/771848) and interact with it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the above information and hints but after implmenting I get the error 'Failed: unknown error: keys should be a string'. I am assuming this is at the .sendKeys.

Comment: @HusainAshraf could u please show me what code are u executing? Thanks!

Comment: Also I am using a Mac

Comment: I am using the first example  var editor = element(by.css("div.ace_content")),
    keys = protractor.Key;
browser.actions()
    .click(editor)
    .sendKeys(keys.chord(keys.COMMAND, "a"))  
    .sendKeys(keys.BACKSPACE)
    .perform();

Comment: @HusainAshraf interesting, could you please show me the complete traceback of the error?

Comment: apologies for the late reply, the full staceback of the error is "Failed: unknown error: keys should be a string
      (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.106)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.5 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 2 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'"

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but could you use the `getWebElement` locator (http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.getWebElement) and then set the value of the element to an empty string? Since that locator returns a DOM reference, it should work. Something like:

```
var editor = element(by.css('div[class*='ace_editor'] > textarea')).getWebElement();
editor.value = '';
```

Comment: Unfortunately all this did was ' ' i.e. nothing to the editor, not clear it. Thank you anyway.